# PHP: CRUD app having problems with Update/Edit

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I'm making a recipes app and I'm having trouble with the update a recipe method. I have the update form and the SQL query. I even checked to see if the form input variables `name`, `description`, and `url` within my `if` statement are the updated values. They are.. and my SQL is valid. Yet, when I fill the out the edit form and hit submit, I get navigated back to the list of recipes page with the recipe I edited not having changed.

Here is my code.

```php
<?php 

$recipe_id = $_GET['recipe_id'];
$recipes_fetch_existing_row_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE id='$recipe_id'");
$recipe = mysqli_fetch_array($recipes_fetch_existing_row_query);
$name = $recipe['name'];
$description = $recipe['description'];
$url = $recipe['url'];

if(isset($_POST['update_recipe'])) {
    $name = $_POST['recipe_name'];
    $description= $_POST['recipe_description'];
    $url = $_POST['recipe_url'];
    $recipe_update_query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE recipe SET name='$name', description='$description', url='$url' WHERE id='$recipe_id'");
    header("Location: ../../../index.php");
}
?>

<form action="../../../index.php" class="update_recipe_form" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="recipe_name" placeholder="name" value="<?php echo $recipe_name ?>" required>
  <textarea name="recipe_description" id="recipe_description" placeholder="Enter a brief description of the recipe"><?php echo $recipe_description; ?></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="recipe_url" id="recipe_url" value="<?php echo $recipe_url ?>" placeholder="url" required>
  <input type="submit" name="update_recipe" id="update_recipe" value="Update">
</form>

Any ideas? :(
```

Comment: Your code is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) preferably with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: on the update try dummy data with no variables and instead of header try echo some words to see if you passed the update and if the update was entered

Comment: Just tried it. An update wasn't entered at all! Any ideas?

Comment: Is `$con` set ? (also, please note that your code is also open to XSS injection. Use proper escaping on the output to the HTML before using this on production)

Comment: Yes, `$con` is set. From `require '../../../config/config.php';` where `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "foodapp");`

Comment: Do you have PHP's `display_errors` set to On? Maybe comment out the redirect after running the query and see if there are errors. If not - try to `var_dump` `$recipe_update_query` in that spot, and also `echo` the query that you construct and examine these values.

Comment: im not very good but you need to breakpoint code with quick error handling use all the suggestions from obe and always try to do things in the code to test it before completing it in this case with a header

Answer (score 0):

is it normal that on the SELECT request you wrote `recipes`, but on the UPDATE request you wrote `recipe`

it was suppose to be the same table, isn't ?

recipes
recipe

Answer (score 0):

When you `POST` the data after submitting the form, the first line will run into an `null` value, because there is no `$_GET['...']`.

```
$recipe_id = $_GET['recipe_id'];
```

Send the ID with your form, maybe as hidden field. You can go on with:

```
if ($recipe_id == null) {
    $recipe_id = $_POST['recipe_id'];
}
```

or

```
$recipe_id = $_REQUEST['recipe_id'];
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

*As the other commentors mentioned, this code is not save for productive use!*